# How to replace NAs in some columns of my data frame with "unknown"

Tags: r

Please I have a data frame containing NAs in some columns but i need to replace the NAs in two column with 'unknown'. I have been trying some codes but not working. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try `replace(df[somecolumns], is.na(df[somecolumns]), "unknown")`

Comment: thank you so much akrun, i tried it but wasn't working so i tried mydata[,5:4][is.na(mydata[,5:4])]<-unknown and it worked.